# How to write to a file in RAM in elixir?

Tags: elixir

So if I open a file in RAM memory (see below code 2) with Elixir, how do I write to that file in RAM and then retrieve its contents once the writing is done? The pattern match returns "#Port<0.11114>", which is not the same as a file handle PID apparently as *IO.write #Port<0.11114>, "hello"* returns an error such as:

**Code 1**

```
** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: {#Port<0.11114>}
    (elixir) lib/io.ex:495: IO.write/2
```

**Code 2**

```
File.open("text.txt", [:ram])
 # => {:ok, {:file_descriptor, :ram_file, #Port<0.11114>}}
```

Comment: Would you mind to share the code that produces the error?

Comment: Saying you need to write to _ram_ strikes me as likely being premature optimization.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci - it is not, I think I have to write to ram because it is being done on a Heroku box which does not let you store files (files written to their ephemeral store would be wiped away)

Answer (score 4):

Ok so this should work for you:

```
{:ok, file} = File.open("text.txt",[:ram, :write])
IO.binwrite(file,"This is a test")
```

Note that if I don't pass the `:write` atom in the `File.open` call, I get an `:ebadf` error when I attempt to write to the file.